# UAC Bypass ‑ Trusted Folder Abuse (WID 4688: credwiz.exe)

Tags: windows, security, active-directory, uac, windows-server-2016

I have received the following info about my active directory server 2016:

> Detected potentially malicious process activity ('UAC Bypass ‑ Trusted
> Folder Abuse ') on your host #ADservername# by leveraging Red Cloak
> threat intelligence within the context of Windows process creation
> (WID 4688) logs.
>
> Summary: UAC Bypass ‑ Trusted Folder Abuse (WID 4688: credwiz.exe) by
> "user account name here" on ADserverName\ServerIP

Kindly help me understand what this implies and what steps I should take.

Notes: This user does not sign out from the server and only "disconnects" and had recently (5 days ago) changed his password. Can this cause such an incident ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer seems to be infected with a virus.

The
[UAC bypass through Trusted Folder abuse](https://redteamer.tips/uac-bypass-through-trusted-folder-abuse/)
is a method for tricking Windows into running programs with
Administrator permissions, by using a blank-terminated
`Windows \System32` folder.

The program doing it is named `credwiz.exe`. The name is legit,
but the program may not be the one that is part of Windows.

See the post
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)